# iHasApp.a framework is not detected by compiler

Tags: objective-c

How to add the framework iHasApp.a framework into my Application bundle framework or framework.I tried to add through bundle phases and add files, but still i am getting the following errors.

1. Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   `_OBJC_CLASS_$_iHasApp`, referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
2. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And I am not able to add this framework.

Comment: How have you tried adding this framework?

Comment: Not clear by this  line "I am not able to add this framework file." What is the exactly issue?

Comment: i have added to bundle resources and also i have added to framework, in both ways i tried, but build and run always gives the errors as shown above.

Comment: I don't know what iHasApp is, but I'm suspicious of the .a and framework used in the same sentence.  Frameworks are dynamic library only, aren't they?

Comment: are you trying on simulator or device?

Comment: have you added header files?. Please read here is the description about that framework:http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php. Check how to implement section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of iHasApp here. From your description, you are using the static library from http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php

As Armaan asked, are you trying to run it on the Simulator? As per the warning on the website, iHasApp was not compiled to run on the Simulator. The warning you are receiving indicates that symbols are not being found for the i386 architecture, namely the iOS Simulator.

**You will only be able to compile that project on an actual device.**

*The following is not meant as an advertisement*: iHasApp is now being maintained as a new, more comprehensive software as a service at https://www.iHasApp.com. It is currently in the late stages of beta. If you would like to participate, then sign up for an account and email me at daniel@ihasapp.com. This newer framework will run on the Simulator (although it is somewhat pointless).

Comment: can i know with this project.. we can find the installed application in iphone? what does find findApps do?

Comment: And  Aimitay what is appSchemesSuccess,I need the installed app names.If that is possible for our phones, it will be great

Comment: Please work with the new framework. The old library is outdated. Regardless, either project comes with an example app that demonstrates how to retrieve all of the information that you are interested in.

Comment: https://github.com/iHasApp/iHasApp-API
You will need to have an account and API key from www.ihasapp.com

Comment: can you give me the api key please

Comment: Go to https://www.ihasapp.com/register and sign up for an account. Your API key will be on your dashboard.